# Const shows as NaN

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a random name feature for naming items, Now i have everything working, Except one piece in the code, Where it displays a const as NaN, Here is my code;

```js
let inventoryOne = '123456789012345678901234';
if (!inventoryOne == '000000000000000000000000') {
  var NameDecode1 = inventoryOne.slice(-22);
  var NameDecode2 = NameDecode1.slice(1);
  var NameDecode3 = NameDecode1.slice(-1);

  if (NameDecode2 == 0) var nameOneCompleted = 'Wrath of ';
  if (NameDecode2 == 1) var nameOneCompleted = 'Legendary ';
  if (NameDecode2 == 2) var nameOneCompleted = 'Rumored ';
  if (NameDecode2 == 3) var nameOneCompleted = 'Stolen ';
  if (NameDecode2 == 4) var nameOneCompleted = 'Sane ';
  if (NameDecode2 == 5) var nameOneCompleted = 'Bane of ';
  if (NameDecode2 == 6) var nameOneCompleted = 'Tsars ';
  if (NameDecode2 == 7) var nameOneCompleted = 'Luminous ';
  if (NameDecode2 == 8) var nameOneCompleted = 'Fated ';
  if (NameDecode2 == 9) var nameOneCompleted = 'Sadistic ';

  if (NameDecode3 == 0) var nameTwoCompleted = 'Isildur';
  if (NameDecode3 == 1) var nameTwoCompleted = 'Menace';
  if (NameDecode3 == 2) var nameTwoCompleted = 'Tsarigaze';
  if (NameDecode3 == 3) var nameTwoCompleted = 'Sly';
  if (NameDecode3 == 4) var nameTwoCompleted = 'Markists';
  if (NameDecode3 == 5) var nameTwoCompleted = 'Freedom';
  if (NameDecode3 == 6) var nameTwoCompleted = 'Stars';
  if (NameDecode3 == 7) var nameTwoCompleted = 'Balances';
  if (NameDecode3 == 8) var nameTwoCompleted = 'Narsissists';
  if (NameDecode3 == 9) var nameTwoCompleted = 'Rights';

  const fullName = ' ' + nameOneCompleted + nameTwoCompleted;
  console.log(nameOneCompleted + nameTwoCompleted);
  console.log(fullName);
  if (fullName.length > 9) {
    fullName.slice(-3);
    fullNameDone = fullName + '...';
  } else {
    fullNameDone = fullName;
  }

  console.log(fullNameDone);
}
```

Now I have tried and tried everything I could possibly think of, I tried some google jutsu but to none of my luck, I cannot figure out what this issue is.

The `fullNameDone` and `fullName` display as NaN

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Comment: Hmm, you probably shouldn't be declaring the variables inside the if blocks!

Comment: `var n1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f','g','h','i']; var nameOneCompleted = n1[NameDecode2];`

Comment: @epascarello How does this work? And how would i use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things wrong with your code

1. You declare `nameOneCompleted` inside your `if` so it's undefined elsewhere. Same for `nameTwoCompleted`. You should define them in the upper [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)
2. Your if condition is always truthy thus useless
3. Use const and let instead of the deprecated var
4. You don't need to do 10 ifs, just define an array and pick the n-th element
5. Use [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) when naming js variables: its `nameDecode2`, not `NameDecode2`
6. `nameDecode2` was a string of several characters, you probably meant to only take the first one, you don't need to slice `nameDecode1` for that btw, just use string index. Also convert it to a number before indexing the string.
7. Don't slice when building substrings, just use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), it's much easier
8. I don't know what you tried to do with the ellipsis but it was wrong, also be aware that the CSS [`text-overflow: ellipsis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) might come more handy than trimming the string on the JS side

That should be good:

```js
const inventoryOne = '123456789012345678901234';
const nameDecode1 = inventoryOne.slice(-22);
const nameDecode2 = +nameDecode1[1];
const nameDecode3 = +nameDecode1[2];

const nameOneCompleted = [
  'Wrath of ',
  'Legendary ',
  'Rumored ',
  'Stolen ',
  'Sane ',
  'Bane of ',
  'Tsars ',
  'Luminous ',
  'Fated ',
  'Sadistic ',
][nameDecode2];
const nameTwoCompleted = [
  'Isildur',
  'Menace',
  'Tsarigaze',
  'Sly',
  'Markists',
  'Freedom',
  'Stars',
  'Balances',
  'Narsissists',
  'Rights',
][nameDecode3]

const fullName = `${nameOneCompleted} ${nameTwoCompleted}`;
const fullNameDone = fullName.length > 9
  ? `${fullName.substring(0, 6)}...`
  : fullName;
console.log({ fullName, fullNameDone });
```